# What does "%d! = %ld'n" mean in this code?

Tags: c

I'm still a beginner at C, so I'm finding difficulty in understanding "%d! = %ld". 
I know that %d and %ld are respectively used for an integer and long, so "! =" is confusing me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
long factorial(int);
int main() {
  int n;
  long f;
  printf("Enter an non-negative integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n < 0)
    printf("Negative integers are not allowed.\n");
  else {
    f = factorial(n);
    printf("%d! = %ld\n", n, f); //what does this mean?
  }
  return 0; }
long factorial(int n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return(n * factorial(n-1)); }
```

Comment: That's just the mathematical notation for the [factorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). It doesn't affect the `%d` format specifier in any way.

Comment: have you looked at the output for clues?  like the fact that the  `=` is actually printed in the statement?

Comment: `"! ="` of `printf("%d! = %ld\n"` will print 3 characters: `'!'`, `' '`, `'='`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This will print:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

- `%d`, i.e. the decimal value of `int n`
- `! =`, i.e. the literal character sequence
- `%ld`, i.e. the decimal value of `long f`

Answer (score 2):

`%d` and `%ld` are the formatting placeholders for `int` and `long int` in `printf`. The exclamation point is just the factorial symbol, as mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

printf() allows you to print a string with variables inside of it. Let's say you have a variable `i`, containing an integer, 7.

```
printf("My variable is %d", i);
```

Will print

```
My variable is 7
```

to the console! That's because %d is how you tell printf(), "Hey, put an integer variable here!". The integer is then supplied as the next argument to the function. In your case, %d represents the integer `n`, and %ld represents the *long* integer `f`. Since f might be really big, we make it a long, which means more bytes are allocated to it internally on your computer. So for example, if we wanted to get the factorial of 5 and print it, we might do the following:

```
printf("Factorial of %d equals %ld\n", 5, factorial(5))
// this will print "Factorial of 5 is 120" then a newline
```

Oh, and `\n` just means print a newline afterwords!

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d! = %ld\n", n, f); //what does this mean?
```

`%d` - print an integer as a signed decimal number.

`l` - specifies that the argument is a `long int` or `unsigned long int` as appropriate. `%ld` then prints a `long int` or `unsigned long int`

The printed text will become something like

```
n! = f
```

(factorial notation `n!`)